# Kotlin type specific object declaration

Tags: kotlin, jvm

I want to make a class that can be declared with specific type operation. Like this (I don't know what this is called):

```kotlin
val div: Division = Division<Indonesia>("Division number 17th")
val div1 = Division<Palestine>("Division number 15")
```

Here is some other code:

```kotlin
class Division(name: String) {
  // secret...
}
```

How I can make things like this:

```
Division<Indonesia>("How?")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about generics. [Here's the Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) covering the basics, [here's the Kotlin-specific stuff](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html). You give the class a generic type like this:

```
class Division<T>(name: String)
```

That's the most basic example... but I think you need to read the generics tutorial I linked